# The type `Kaitai.Elf' already contains a definition for `Bits'

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I am trying to compile the code from this stackexchange answer: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16631/12521

After adding the System imports and a class definition, I downloaded `Elf.cs` from http://formats.kaitai.io/elf/csharp.html and tried to compile it `mcs -out:unpack.exe Elf.cs unpack.cs`. However, this fails with the following errors:

```
Elf.cs(890,21): error CS0102: The type `Kaitai.Elf' already contains a definition for `Bits'
Elf.cs(97,21): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Elf.cs(895,23): error CS0102: The type `Kaitai.Elf' already contains a definition for `Endian'
Elf.cs(16,21): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Running `mcs Elf.cs` produces the same errors. Unfortunately, I am not a C# expert. How can I get this to compile properly.

Answer (score 0):

To fix those errors, you need to rename the properties on line 890 and 895 because the name conflicts with an enum defined earlier in the file. For example, you could just add `Value` on the end:

```
public Bits BitsValue { get { return _bits; } }

//

public Endian EndianValue { get { return _endian; } }
```

However, this file cannot be compiled on it's own as:

1. The classes all inherit from something called `KaitaiStruct` that isn't present here.
2. The object `KaitaiStream` is used several times and is also not present in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 3 years later, C# version of ELF.ksy format definition can't be compiled to C#...
The only option is to use an [old one, from 2017](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_formats/blob/58d6977f19969f1468beaeb50ddee9162a30d4b8/executable/elf.ksy). It still has errors, but they are easier to fix.